# Can't open declaration in eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse

I cannot open declaration of any java interface or classes. I press CNTRL and hover over the interface and try to open the declaration then it says no source found as in the image.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The class you are trying to look at is part of the Java runtime code.

It looks like  you only have a JRE installed which does not include the runtime source. Install a JDK instead of the JRE, the JDK includes the source. Eclipse will automatically find the source once you are using a JDK.

Note. You have Java 8, for newer versions of Java only the JDK is available.